# Array parameter Vs direct parameters to pass to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, function

I need to call a js-function with many parameters. Assume,

```
function Create()
{
    var a = $("#a").val();
    var b = $("#b").val();
    var c = $("#c").val();
    var d = $("#d").val();
    var e = $("#e").val();
    var f = $("#f").val();

    var arraydata = [a, b, c, d, e, f];

    //: 1. calling js-function with direct parameters
    var IsError = Validate_param(a, b, c, d, e, f); 

    //: 2. calling js-function with array
    var IsError = Validate_array(arraydata); 

    if (IsError == 0)
    {
          //: Do some operations...
    }
}
```

The validation js-function's are,

```
function Validate_param(a, b, c, d, e, f)
{
      alert("The value of a : "+ a);
}

function Validate_array(arraydata)
{
      alert("The value of a : "+ arraydata[0]);
}
```

My doubt is which is best way to call a js-function with many parameters.
Here, i wrote 2 js-functions for validations. Which function will give better performance, `Validate_param()` or `Validate_array()` ?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I think that, for only a few parameters, the difference would be negligible.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the array overload as you can already access passed arguments from the `arguments` array.

Anyway, you shouldn't worry about a small potential performance difference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. So, the difference of calling this 2 function performance are small potential only.. right ? & where can i test this type of js function performance through online ?